# Do coins from Chance Time count for the Rich Bonus star?

Tags: mario-party-superstars

The Rich Bonus star in Mario Party Superstars is awarded for earning the most coins during the game. Does this include coins earned from Chance Time? What about coins lost during Chance Time?

Comment: Bonus question: Does the Rich Bonus include coins stolen with Boo?

Comment: Good question. Fwiw, MP 1 through 5 had the following requirement:
"- This is given to whoever reached the highest coin count during the game." I can try to experiment with it though to confirm.

Comment: This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MARIOPARTY/comments/qipvfr/i_actually_like_the_way_the_rich_star_works_now/) seems to indicate quite clearly that it is now "total coins _earned_" and not "highest coins _total_ at any point".

Comment: @Mat I can confirm, it's most coins earned in Superstars, not coin total. You can see it on the results screen.